# Does a CXCallDirectoryProvider's addIdentificationEntry data get used in Messages?

Tags: ios, callkit, ios-extensions

I have put together a CallKit extension to id incoming phone calls.  What I'm wondering (and a bit surprised by) is that these identifications only seem to work with phone calls but not SMS/iMessages coming from the same number.

Is there a way to get the Messages app to pay attention to these extension-provided identifications?

Comment: For my case, it is even not working for phone calls